# Optimization over the set of all bounded probability measures

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, probability-distributions, convex-optimization

Given $X$ finite, fix a continuous function $\theta \in \Delta^+ (X) \to [0,1]$, fix a probability measure $\mu^*$, and a $\varepsilon > 0$. Consider:
$$
\max_{\mu \in \Delta^+ (X)} \theta (\mu), \quad \text{such that } d(\mu ,\mu^*) \leq \varepsilon
$$
where $\Delta^+ (X)$ is the set of all sigma-additive probability measures with finite support, and $d(\mu ,\mu^*)$ is defined as a distance measure.

Does this optimization problem has a solution? How could I tackle such a optimization Problem?

Comment: Depending on $d$, which is not defined, this problem has a solution since $\theta$ is a continuous function defined on a compact set.

Comment: How is $d$ defined?

Comment: Since $\Delta^+(X)$ is nothing else as the $|X|$-dimensional simplex $S$, your problem can be reformulated as: Determine $x \in S$ which maximizes $x \to \Theta(x)$ on $\{x \in S \colon d(x,x^*)$, where $x^*$ is some fixed $x^* \in S$. Without knowing $\Theta$, at least its structure (linear, quadratic, ?) and $d$ there is no general answer to your problem!